# submit button in django refreshes the page without saving

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am trying to save data in ORM via a form but when I click on the submit button all it does is refresh the page with the same data.

HTML

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% crispy form %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block content %}
  <h2 class="mb-3">Add a Warehouse</h2>
  <div class="row">

    <form method="post" class="col-md-12 proct-form" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
        {{ form.owner|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
        {{ form.warehouse_name|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
        {{ form.warehouse_email|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
        {{ form.warehouse_contact|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
        {{ form.warehouse_city|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
        {{ form.warehouse_pincode|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
        {{ form.warehouse_state|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
        {{ form.warehouse_pan|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
        {{ form.warehouse_gst|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-0">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        <a href="{% url 'employee:warehouse_table' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" role="button">Nevermind</a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Views.py

```
@method_decorator([login_required, employee_required], name='dispatch')
class WarehouseFormView(CreateView):
    model = Warehouse
    fields = "__all__"
    template_name = 'packsapp/employee/warehouseForm.html'

    def form_valid (self, form):
        product = form.save(commit=False)
        product.save()
        messages.success(self.request, 'The Warehouse was created with success!')
        return redirect('employee:warehouse_table')
```

Is there a problem with my views.py or do I need to change my templates? 
All the other forms in the app are created the same way and they work fine

Comment: Where is the rest of the template - in particular the form? What are you saving? Are you displaying any form errors?

Comment: @DanielRoseman  I updated the question with the complete template. I am trying to save the data which I fill in the form.

Comment: You're not displaying any form-level (as opposed to field-level) errors. Add `{{ form.non_field_errors }}`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It doesnot display anything, also in the terminal I am getting `[10/Oct/2019 15:31:32] "POST /employee/warehouse/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 19560`. So the data is being sent, right ?

Comment: Try with `{{ form.errors }}`. Yes, the data is being sent, but a 200 indicates that it is re-displaying the same page, which will happen when there is a validation error. (Possibly a required field that you're not including in the form.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks It showed me the field that I was missing